# Should test cleanup happen in each individual test method or in a general test cleanup?

Tags: test-design, testng

For example, let's say I have these tests:

```
test1() {
    signIn();

    // Do some testing

    signOut();
}

test2() {
    signIn();

    // Do some testing

    signOut();
}
```

Would it be better to have `signOut()` be done in a common cleanup method like the following?

```
test1() {
    signIn();

    // Do some testing
}

test2() {
    signIn();

    // Do some testing
}

@AfterMethod
testCleanup() {
    signOut();
}
```

Comment: Either/or . . . junit-style frameworks do a setup/teardown before and after each test.  The real answer to this depends on what you're trying to test, and there's no one size fits all . . .

Answer (score 2):

You can go either way.

You might include these steps in each test, because they're actions that an actual user will take. Meaning that they can potentially fail in specific circumstances, and thus you'll want them linked to that specific test case.

However, signIn() and signOut() look like actions every tester will perform manually as well for every non-automated test. So if they're not likely to fail, and these tests are always run in conjunction with manual tests, you could extract them from individual test cases.

Personally I'd go with the first option.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a really good reason to repeat yourself, don't. Putting in an explicit login and logout step in each test is needless repetition if every test must perform a login and logout.